# Why isn't the MySQL extension loading?

Tags: mysql, extension

Please help! I've been going at it for a while and I can't get it to install, keep getting the ol message below.

Running on my own server.
MYSql, PHP, Apache instaled.
Already uncommented the extension in my php.ini.
The module is installed and can see the mysql.so file.
Already ran phpinfo() http://guerraysaenz.us/test.php

Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Apache error log:

```
PHP Warning: Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Jul 07 11:59:23 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.7(2011-06-30) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/modulename.extension' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/modulename.extension: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 12.04

Comment: I really need some help. I usually come to a conclusion on fixing an issue, but I hit rock bottom on this one..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try backing up `/etc/php5`, then doing

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

This will remove all of your configurations for those packages. Then re install them

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

That should put fresh configs for those modules back in place. Then you can compare what is there to your backup of `/etc/php5` and probably figure out what the problem was.